# Quotient space of Grassmannian

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, sg.symplectic-geometry

The Grassmannian $G(k,2k)$ is equipped with a nice $\mathbb Z_2$ action with respect to a non-degenerate symplectic bilinear form: $1.V=V^{perp}$. Is there a reference where the ring of polynomial invariants is studied ? What is the quotient (the orbit space) $G(k,2k)/\mathbb Z_2$ identified with ?

Comment: The subvariety of $G(k,2k)$ that you are considering is the subvariety of maximal isotropic spaces in the ambient space: the Lagrangian-Grassmannian variety. Thus, the ring of invariants is given by the coordinate ring of the Lagrangian-Grassmannian.

Comment: Do you mean polynomials invariant for this $\mathbb{Z}_2$ action, or do you mean polynomials on the space of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ invariant points? @FZaldivar is talking about the latter. The former is the coordinate ring of $G(k,2k)/\mathbb{Z}_2$ and I don't know anything to say about it.

Comment: I am talking about the co-ordinate ring of the quotient $G(k,2k)/\mathbb Z_2$,i.e., the polynomials which are invariant for the $\mathbb Z_2$ action.

Comment: @David Speyer, Is this action same as the one induced from the dynkin aytomorphism ? In the latter case is the ring of invariants known ?

Comment: Do you mean the homogeneous coordinate ring?

Comment: Either the quotient (the orbit space) or the homogeneous coordinate ring of the quotient will do.

Comment: The ring of invariants isn't the same as the homogeneous coordinate ring (indeed it isn't even uniquely defined).

Comment: Okay, I just need the orbit space of this action for my work.

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but for the real grassmannian, I believe $G(2, 4)/\mathbb{Z}_2$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{RP}^2\times\mathbb{RP}^2$.